# How to interact with contract with calldata

Tags: solidity, gnosis-safe

Everything in this post is on rinkeby, not sure if that makes a difference.

So I'm trying to use this payments splitter called 0xSplits and when I call the contract method to update the split on etherscan directly I want to call directly through etherscan everything works fine, but when I try to call the same method with the same parameters via gnosis' UI it seems to get messed up somehow... no errors and the transaction doesn't get rejected/reverted, but it definitely is going wrong somewhere. If relevant, there is some calldata getting passed through like an array of addresses and an array of uint256's, not sure if that helps diagnose the problem.

Here is a sample passing transaction of the same function call I found on etherscan that actually worked as well: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xcbd3ed39ad09d107155bff4571e1ad0ce987689b07cb64b9436338b17a7f0cf9

Comment: How do you create the tx on the Safe UI?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out, it's because of a limitation of the other protocol 0xsplits I was using, not because of gnosis at all. Long story short, rinkeby doesn't play well with 0xSplits and updating or creating splits from a gnosis safe. Good to know!